# How do i define a printed text in python?

Tags: python

I want to define a printed text
For example:

```
print "text"
test = the printed text
if test == text:
 print "yes"
else:
print "no"
```

So how can this be done?
What if i have multiple printed texts how am i going to define them in order to come up with a result? *the if statement*

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot keep track of the strings you are printing yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to define a variable, like this:

```
a = "Printed text"
print(a)
```

And if you want to verify wih another string, use `b = input()` and verify with tis variable.

```
if a == b:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```